# jQueryUI .widget() not registering function

Tags: jquery-ui, widget

I suspect that I'm missing the obvious, but I cannot get the below to work.

I'm trying to create a custom on/off switch, but when ever I load the page I'm greeted with an error -

> $(...).switchButton is not a function

I have `jQuery`/`jQueryUI` included, and there is even an instance of a `jQuery` spinner on the page that was once extended using `.widget()`.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
(function($){

    $.widget('DDUI.switchButton', {

        options: {
            tester: 'This plugin is working...'
        }, // options

        _create: function(){
            console.log(this.options.tester);
        } // _create

    })

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#switch_test').switchButton();
});
```

Comment: Not shure, but isn'nt it `$('input #switch_test')` (extra space in selector)

Comment: No, the input has the ID `switch_test`, so the selector is correct. Besides, it's not the selector causing the error, it's the `switchButton()` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved this issue.

Simply replace this -

```
(function($){
```

With this -

```
$(function(){
```